# Set wallpaper to black and hide hidden files on remote desktop login

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, color-theme, roaming-profiles

My workplace recently introduced some changes to how our Windows 10 remote sessions work.
Every time I log into a new RDP session, the wallpaper is set to a ghastly grey background with a raster pattern that does not transfer well with compression.
Sometimes the theme is reset to a screaming red, and show hidden files is always turned on.

I've asked a couple of the infrastructure staff, but no one wants to admit to these changes, although someone obviously spent time implementing something no one here (all developers) needs.
This forced theme of brutalism roams further into nested RDP sessions.

Is there a way to execute a script on logon that turns off "show hidden files" and switches off the wallpaper (to black)?